# Vim: how do I disable the default LogiPat plugin?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

In Vim 7.4 there's a default plugin called "LogiPat". A command this plugin exposes is `:ELP`, which is shadowing another command I use a lot `:Explore`. For that last command I always use `:E` but since LogiPat exposes `:ELP` I need to type in `:Ex` which is more work.

I don't use the LogiPat plugin and would like to disable it. How do I do this?

I've already tried setting the following line in my .vimrc:

```
let g:loaded_LogiPat = "v3"
```

in the hopes that this would prevent LogiPat from loading. But that did not work.

I'm hoping there's a simple way to do this that does not require me to move or delete the plugin from the `vim/plugin` directory.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a bug in the LogiPat plugin:

```
" Load Once: {{{1
if &cp || exists("loaded_logipat")
 finish
endif
let g:loaded_LogiPat = "v3"
```

It sets `g:loaded_LogiPat` but checks for `loaded_logipat`. (And the file is named `logiPat.vim`. Someone's really inconsistent with their capitalization.)

The workaround is to set

```
let g:loaded_logipat = 1
```

in your `.vimrc`.

Comment: Has anyone reported this to the LogiPat author (or the vim project)?

Comment: Nevermind, I see the latest version (v4b) on the author's webpage has been updated.  Now the filename and variable are "logiPat.vim" and "loaded_logiPat" respectively.

Answer (score 0):

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vim_dev/v00y1305Eng

Sent a patch. You will get fix in later.